# A public version of 37signals' Basecamp?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm using 37signals' Basecamp webapp for collaborating with many people on data standards.  Generally I like the product.  There are a few issues like not being able to easily follow a topic or wiki (writeboard) for changes.  Their wiki-mechanism kind of sucks (finicky, no nested lists, tables, etc).

The biggest issue I have is that I can't seem to make everything public.  Though you should need a login to contribute or collaborate, I want the outside world to see what we're working on as easily as possible.  I want all of our great content to be search engine indexable.  I'd like to not have a separate front end site for the world to see and a different site for us members to collaborate with.

Any webapps like Basecamp that I should be looking at instead?

Comment: Yeah it's crazy how basecamp doesn't support this. It seems they can do it for their own internal projects - http://basecamp.com/public-projects - but not for normal people. Very very lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a combination of Google Apps.

- Google Site for the public view and wiki
- Google Code for code sharing, issue tracking, tasks
- Google Docs for formal documentation
- Google Groups

You can get very creative with this.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SharePoint to solve that problem but unless you have a team of developers, I would not go down that road. I checked on [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net) and there is a startup called [TeamLab](http://www.teamlab.com) that may be just what you need. They even offer a Basecamp import feature. It is offerered as SaaS or Open Source software.

Comment: Just briefly going through their docs and video, I didn't get the impression your projects could be made public.  Can you do this?